# iOS Live Activity: can I remove the margins between different expanded segments?

Tags: ios, activitykit, widgetliveactivity

I've set up a very basic live activity with `.leading`, `.trailing` and `.bottom` segments. I've also applied `.contentMargins(.all, 0)` to each of them, but when I show the activity there's still a margin between each of the segments:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way for me to remove them? Ideally I'd have no gap between leading/trailing and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Inner margins within dynamic island expanded presentation can be removed with a small work around.

You can try using just the `bottom` area/position. The top margin of ~37pts is the only caveat.

```
DynamicIsland {
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                    HStack(){
                        Text("Merged View").font(.title).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height:105)
                        .background(.blue.gradient)
                        .cornerRadius(24)
                    }
            }
```

It will [look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/797Ls.png).

You can alternatively just use `leading` area/position and use `verticalPlacement` parameter inside `dynamicIsland` modifier.

```
DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
                        HStack(){
                            Text("Merged View").font(.title).foregroundColor(.white)
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height:105)
                            .background(.green.gradient)
                            .cornerRadius(24)
                            .dynamicIsland(verticalPlacement: .belowIfTooWide)
                        }
```

I hope this helps